# Missing symbols in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I keep getting this error in Visual Studio 2013:

[image]

Anyone knows how to resolve?

Comment: You've blocked out the one part of the message that might have helped answer the question.  At least tell us if it is a DLL name you recognize, and where it came from (Windows OS, other Microsoft software, third-party software, part of your project).

Comment: It is my own module, a .dll, in the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable 'Just My Code' in the Tools -> options -> Debugging -> General menu.

Just check the box for 'Enable Just My Code'

Comment: I already have done this. That's the problem. Currently I can't see any debugging symbols.

Comment: Try to load all symbols (click on the button Tools -> options -> debugging -> Symbols -> 'load all symbols'

Comment: Did you clicked the button or did you checked the radio button?

Comment: I checked the radio button, and verified the list in excluded modules.